# React Native WebView enable caching

Tags: react-native, android-webview, wkwebview

Is caching already enabled in the React Native WebView by default? If not, how can I do it, do I need to use some libraries? Is there a way to check if the WebView is loading from cache, or downloading resources again from the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that caching is enabled by default.

Have you checked out [react-native-offline-cache-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline-cache-webview)? I think it can help you out.

Comment: Yes I'm aware and am already using this library, but as it sometimes seems in the Chrome Inspector (and also said by the author) this library fetches everything when network is available

Comment: I used this library after forking it

Comment: The above library worked fine, but I have had to fork it, because the orginal library, was caching everything (even dynamic pages), and there was no control provided to stop using props. 

Feel free to have a look, but honestly, my fork still a WIP where I want to add React props and get them in native code to control what can be cached, what pages to load, etc.

If you have knowledge of these or have a better approach, please consider reforking my fork and improving it further.

Comment: My fork is located at https://github.com/dgoenka/react-native-offline-cache-webview